# Draw graph where nodes have data

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, graphviz, graph-visualization

I have a directed graph that contains some complex data. I want to draw this graph and have each node represented as a table. Is there a way to achieve this?

All plotting examples I find only have a label or something simple drawn into the node.

FYI: I am currently using networkx

[image]

Comment: Show an example of your data. Is it a list or a dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using graphviz, the label can represent something more complex like a table.

Graphviz offers two variants:

1. [Record based nodes](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/shapes.html#record)

Record based nodes offer a simple way to display a simple table in a label:

```
node1[shape=record, label="{A|1 May|3 May|-1}|{1|2 May|4 May|2}"]
```

However, it is not possible to add style attributes (font, color, ...).

2. [HTML-like labels](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/shapes.html#html)

HTML-like labels use html-like markup to define the appearance of the label, which allows for complex tables including style information such as bold fonts, colors, alignment, ...

```
 node2[shape=none, label=<
 <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
    <TR>
        <TD><B>A</B></TD>
        <TD><B>1</B></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>1 May</TD>
        <TD>2 May</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>3 May</TD>
        <TD>4 May</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>-1</TD>
        <TD>2</TD>
    </TR>
 </TABLE>
 >]
```